# Accumulate sum of all element in list having integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the sum of all numbers for each list through itertool accumulate function:
This is the code:

```
from itertools import *
import operator

list_numbers = [[45,43,56,67],[41,423,526,627,897],[545,453,656,667]]

Iterable_list = iter(list_numbers)

while(True):
    try:
        print(list(accumulate(next(Iterable_list),operator.add))[-1])
    except StopIteration as ex:
        print(ex)
        break
```

The above works well.

if I try to take out the max of each list:

```
while(True):
    try:
        print(list(accumulate(next(Iterable_list),func=max))[-1])
    except StopIteration as ex:
        print(ex)
        break
```

this also works well.

My interpretation was, if I use `func = sum`, it will do the sum of each list like I tried below but it prompts error
message:

```
'int' object is not iterable


while(True):
    try:
        print(list(accumulate(next(Iterable_list),func=sum))[-1])
    except StopIteration as ex:
        print(ex)
        break
```

Why it doesn't it work and in which scenario can we use `func = sum`?

Comment: Why not use: `print([max(l) for l in list_numbers])` and `print([sum(l) for l in list_numbers])`?

Comment: Yeah, `accumulate` seems like overkill here. `for x in list_numbers: print(sum(x))`.

Comment: true.. it can be achieved that way! Even, my problem is solved with first code snippet(operator.add). I'm trying to learn accumulate function,

Comment: See the "Roughly equivalent to" section of https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate. Pay attention to the line that calls the function you pass in and note how the call is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could understand better the behavior of [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) if you use a lambda function to explore the inputs that `func` will receive.

Let's use `lambda x: print(x)` instead of `sum` first, to print the values:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Ok, so `func` will receive two values. Let's try `lambda x, y: print(x, y)`:

```
45 43
None 56
None 67
None
41 423
None 526
None 627
None 897
None
545 453
None 656
None 667
None
```

> Why are we seeing `None`? Because `print()` does not return any value, so it returns a `None`.

This means that `func` should receive two values from the iterator (L1 and L2), apply an operation on both values and return a single value C. Then, apply the same operation on the previous result (C) with the next value in the iterator (L3).

---

**Why [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) fails?**

Well, because it expects a single argument, an iterable, and optionally accepts a second (`start`). Now, `itertools.accumulate` is passing two values and Python assumes you're trying to use `sum(L1, start=L2)`, but `L1` is not iterable since its just a number... `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

**In which scenario can we use `func=sum`?**

`sum()` could help us if it could receive two values and return a single one, which is possible (`sum(iterable, start=start)`). Now, consider that the output of `sum` will be used as the first input of `sum` with the next element in the iterable, something like: `sum(sum(L1, start=L2), start=L3)` and so on. This means that `sum(L1, start=L2)` should return an iterable for us to be able to use `sum`. It's hard to find an example for this, meaning that `sum` might not be the best option for any particular case when using `itertools.accumulate`, but this doesn't mean that `sum` is not useful by itself.

Comment: Awesome.. thanks for such a lightning response! sum() function definition is different than what I thought.. it requires an iterable as first input..   It works when i use normal addition using lambda like below        while(True):
    try:
        print(list((accumulate(next(Iterable_list),func=lambda x,y: x + y)))[-1])
    except StopIteration as ex:
        print(ex)
        break

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using Zip() or map() method or using numpy.

Using zip():

```
def nested_sum(lst):
      
 return [sum(i) for i in zip(*lst)]
      
lst = [[2, 4, 6], [2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]] # A Sample List
print(nested_sum(lst))

#Output
[12,5,6]
```